# Can´t find proper MSVCP140d.dll dependency while loading my own DLL, even though its present in the folder

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, msvcrt

today I encountered a problem.

I´m building my own DLL(C++), that is used as a plugin to OpenCities Map. On my local computer(the same computer that is used for developing the project), everything works fine, my DLL is loaded without troubles and everything is okay. However, today I tried the same thing on virtual machine to see if it works fine also on other machines. Thats when I encountered problem saying that my DLL could not be loaded because of some of its dependencies (that was my guess).

So I started investigation. I used **DependencyWalker** and also **Proccess Monitor** to see how are the DLLs loaded and what fails. Output confused me even more.

On my local machine, when I opened the DLL, it could load also the dependencies like MSVCP140D.dll.

[image]

I assume that from the fact that I can even see its content and the entire path (when I clicked to display the full paths as well). The proccess monitor also shows that it is loaded correctly from the folder I saw in Dependency walker.
[image]

At first I saw that it failed at the upper case DLL called MSVCP140D.dll, but then it went to SUCCESS with the correct path (System32/msvcp140d.dll).

Now the virtual machine (or other computer). Here, I cant see a path to the msvcp140d.dll in the dependency walker, so I cannot also see the content (or other includes from that DLL)

[image]

Then, it could not load these DLLs even in the process manager, even though it looked the correct path. Problem is, that it looks for the upper case DLL name MSVCP140d.dll (and I can literally see the msvcp140d.dll in the system32 folder) with the result NAME NOT FOUND. Why it looks for the MSVCP140D.dll instead of msvcp140d.dll ? I mean, I would expect the same behavior like on my local machine, to start looking for the lower case dll version, but it still looked just for the upper case versions.

[image]

I´ve tried to install the VS redistributables, .NET framework, but nothing worked. I´m building the project using VS17, its x64 DLL also with the /clr and /MDd switches (if it helps).

I would ask on specific OpenCities Map forum, but that looks for me like some kind of general building problem, something that I missed.

Do you guys have any advice? Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be shipping code based on the debugging versions of the runtime library DLLs.  Microsoft do not support this.  DLL names are not case-sensitive, BTW, so that's a red herring.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I know I shouldn´t ship the debug versions, but I´ve tried it only for testing purposes, because on my local machine it works. Actually, if DLL names are not case sensitive, why it couldn´t load the DLL even though it looked the exact path where the DLL is? To be honest that was my only clue

Comment: It may be because a dependency of the DLL is missing, did you check for that?

Comment: Thats was an excellect hint!! Even though I feel embarrased and I can´t believe I didn´t think about this detail, about checking also the sub-dependencies of these DLLs. Even though the msvcp140d was in the system, the vcruntimed was missing in the virtual machine (thats when I really understood why I should test it really with Release).. At first I thought that it is not a problem, because i was thinking that Dependency walker would warn me about what sub-dependency is missing and not just the whole one. It works now. I still have a long way to use the tools properly. Thanks for your help!